# Mobile email images are not downloading on mobile device - multiple platforms

Tags: image, email, mobile

I'm building a mobile friendly email and the main images do not load when the email initially loads (the small facebook and twitter icons in the footer do load). I say, loading rather than displaying bc there aren't any red x's on the screen or any indication there there should be images there. However, if I go back to the inbox and click on the email to view it again, the images load just fine. I tested this on the iPhone and Android in the web email clients, yahoo and gmail, and it's happening in all those instances. I've received mobile emails in the past where the images load just fine, so it's got to be my code. I've been having a heard time finding the answer to this, so I hope someone here is familiar with this issue and can help me out. Let me know if you have questions. I appreciate the help, very much.

Note: I discovered it's also not displaying the images in Safari but only on first load. When the page is reloaded - just like in the mobile browsers, it loads the images.

Here's a link from Campaign Monitor:
http://testclient.createsend4.com/t/ViewEmail/y/8B8E5FE792737812

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- If you delete this tag, the sky will fall on your head -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
img {display:block; border:0;}
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} -->
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:100%;height:100%;">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<tr><td>

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="content" style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="37" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<tr>
<td valign="bottom" style="text-align:center; color:#5b5a5a; font-size:11px;">
Email not displaying correctly? <webversion style="color:#5b5a5a; text-decoration:underline;">View it in your browser</webversion>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="34" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<tr>
<td style="color:#939497; text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="color:#5c9b14;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><strong>Shop Online</strong></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#" style="color:#5c9b14;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><strong>Find A Store</strong></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#" style="color:#5c9b14;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><strong>Forward To A Friend</strong></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<tr><td>
<div class="content" style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td><a href="http://beyondrto.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_06.png" width="100%" style="display:block;border:0;color:#ffffff;" alt="Beyond RTO Home Furnishings &amp; Appliances For Less." border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>


<!-- PROMO -->
<div class="content" style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td><a href="http://beyondrto.com/campaign/hristmas_in_july" target="_blank"><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_07.jpg" border="0" width="100%" style="display:block;" alt="Celebrate Christmas in July - Register to Win $1000 Shopping Spree!"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table> 

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_08.jpg" border="0" width="100%" style="display:block;" alt="Plus enjoy this bonus offer and SAVE!"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_09.jpg" width="100%" border="0" style="display:block;" alt="Reveal Your Deal with Beyond RTO!"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<!-- FOOTER -->


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<tr><td>
<div class="content" style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td><a href="http://beyondrto.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_10.png" width="100%" border="0" style="display:block;" alt="Beyond RTO Home Furnishings &amp; Appliances For Less."/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="21" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:13px;color:#939497;"><a href="#" style="color:#82c13a;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><strong>Shop Online</strong></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#" style="color:#82c13a;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><strong>Find A Store</strong></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#" style="color:#82c13a;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><strong>Forward To A Friend</strong></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_13.png" width="40" height="44" border="0" style="display:block;"/></td>
<td><img src="images/2959_BYRTO_July_emailer_14.png" width="36" height="44" border="0" style="display:block;"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="50" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" border="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:10px;color:#bebebe;line-height:14px;">
&copy; Copyright 2013 Baber's. All Rights Reserved.<br/>
You are currently subscribed as [email]. Click here to <unsubscribe style="color:#82c13a;text-decoration:underline;">unsubscribe</unsubscribe>.</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>

</td></tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. Once I discovered this was also happening in Safari, it was easier to trouble shoot. I figured out that some of the tables did not have a width defined and Safari requires a width value and so do mobile email clients apparently. I normally have widths on all my tables, so didn't realize that was the culprit this time.